# How to Fetch specific api from database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

```
 componentDidMount() {
fetch("http://localhost:5000/customers/:id")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((info) => {
    this.setState({ info });
  })
  .then((err) => console.log(err));
```

}

How to fetch a specific data from database by sending the required ID with URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the format string syntax from javascript and add the id to the url-string with that.

```
const id = 42
fetch(`http://localhost:5000/customers/${id}`)
```

Comment: For example if I login with an ID in form, How to add the form ID to the URL when I click LOGIN?